# Python Check a 2d list for empty strings?

Tags: python

I've been trying to figure out this problem for multiple hours and still no luck. I'm in the process of writing Connect4 in Python for a school assignment and I need a function that checks if the board is full.

Here is my **init** function

```
    def __init__( self, width, height ): 
    self.width = width 
    self.height = height 
    self.data = [] # this will be the board 

    for row in range( self.height ): 
        boardRow = [] 
        for col in range( self.width ): 
            boardRow += [' '] 
        self.data += [boardRow]
```

My **repr** function

```
    def __repr__(self): 
    #print out rows & cols 
    s = '' # the string to return 
    for row in range( self.height ): 
        s += '|' # add the spacer character 
        for col in range( self.width ): 
            s += self.data[row][col] + '|' 
        s += '\n' 

s += '--'*self.width + '-\n'

for col in range( self.width ):
    s += ' ' + str(col % 10)
s += '\n'

return s
```

And what I have for my isFull function

```
    def isFull(self):
# check if board is full
for row in range(0,(self.height-(self.height-1))):
    for col in range(0,self.width):
    if (' ') not in self.data[row][col]:
        return True
```

I want to check and see if there this ' ' (a space) within the data list. At least I think that's my problem, I'm not experienced in python so I may be misreading my issue. If anyone has any ideas I'm glad to listen.

Comment: So, what is your problem? Which method doesn't work? How does it not work? And please align your code properly. Also, what is this `range(0,(self.height-(self.height-1)))`? It is the same as `range(0,1)`

Comment: I need a function that can check if there is a space ' ' anywhere within a 2d list

Comment: You might like to post your code on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) once you have it working (not with major bugs/errors) and get some ideas for improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if there is any space, it means the board is not full?

Various versions:

```
# straightforward but deep
def is_full(self):
    for row in self.data:
        for cell in row:
            if cell == ' ':
                return False
    return True
```

---

```
# combine the last two
def is_full(self):  # python functions/methods are usually lower case
    for row in self.data:  # no need to index everything like c
        if any(cell == ' ' for cell in row):  # any/all are convenient testers
            return False  # if you find even one, it's done.
    return True  # if you couldn't disqualify it, then it looks full
```

---

```
# one line, not especially readable
def is_full(self):
    return not any(cell == ' ' for row in d for cell in row)
```

Comment: I honestly can't thank you enough. I'm not much of a programmer so I've been trying to figure this out for hours and this worked perfectly. Thank you again

Comment: great! I would appreciate it if you could formally accept the answer. Warm fuzzies all around.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic for `isFull` method is incorrect.

In your current code, you are returning `True` from `isFull` as soon as you found a non-empty cell. That is incorrect. You should do the opposite.

You should be doing what kobejohn had posted earlier: to return `False` as soon as you found an empty cell.

And in Python you should work without indices if possible, and use Python natural looping, like in the code kobejohn had posted.